# Parsing arrays with Jackson

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I would like to parse the following Json using Jackson but I am not sure at all how should I construct the entity.

```
   [
      CHAN_ID, 
      [
        [
          SYMBOL, 
          STATUS, 
          AMOUNT, 
          BASE_PRICE, 
          MARGIN_FUNDING, 
          MARGIN_FUNDING_TYPE,
          PL,
          PL_PERC,
          PRICE_LIQ,
          LEVERAGE,
           ...
        ], 
        ...
      ]
    ]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Position {

        @JsonProperty("SYMBOL")
        private String symbol;
        @JsonProperty("STATUS")
        private String status;
        @JsonProperty("AMOUNT")
        private Decimal amount;
        @JsonProperty("BASE_PRICE")
        private Decimal basePrice;
        @JsonProperty("MARGIN_FUNDING")
        private Integer marginFunding;
        @JsonProperty("MARGIN_FUNDING_TYPE")
        private Decimal marginFundingType;
        @JsonProperty("PL")
        private Decimal profitLoss;
        @JsonProperty("PL_PERC")
        private Decimal profitLossPercentage;
        @JsonProperty("PRICE_LIQ")
        private Decimal liquidationPrice;
        @JsonProperty("LEVERAGE")
        private Decimal leverage;
    }
```

This thing I am trying to parse, seems like has an array of Position but also before it has that CHAN_ID, should I construct some sort of wrapper class for that?

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Positions {

    @JsonProperty("CHAN_ID")
    private String channelId;

    @JsonProperty("positions")
    private List<Position> positions;

}
```

What do you think, is this correct? Also don't mind those annotations on the top of the classes, it is just Lombok.
Currently this implementation gives me the following error when I try parsing:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of `model.Positions` out of START_ARRAY token  at
>   [Source: (String)"['ps', [ [ 'aa', 'bb', 123.45, 123.45, 567, 123.45,
>   123.45, 123.45, 123.45, 123.45]] ]"; line: 1, column: 1]

To test this I am just using an ObjectMapper:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            Positions positions = objectMapper.readValue("['ps', [ [ 'aa', 'bb', 123.45, 123.45, 567, 123.45, 123.45, 123.45, 123.45, 123.45]] ]", Positions.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input JSON is structured as nested arrays, binding with `@JsonProperty` does not have much sense, because none of these property keys are present in the input JSON. Here they make sense only if you wanted to transform afterwards the deserialized data into a JSON with property-value pairs.

To read this JSON structure properly, you will have to implement a custom deserializer, because in this case properties cannot be mapped with their values automatically. The deserializer can be an implementation of Jackson's `JsonDeserializer` or `StdDeserializer`. For example, the below implementation works:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class PositionsDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Positions> {

  public PositionsDeserializer() {
    super(Positions.class);
  }

  @Override
  public Positions deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
    Object[] positionsProps = p.readValueAs(Object[].class);
    if (positionsProps != null && positionsProps.length > 0) {
      String chanId = (String) positionsProps[0];
      List<Position> positionsList =
          ((List<List<?>>) positionsProps[1]).stream()
              .map(this::deserializePosition)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
      Positions positions = new Positions();
      positions.setChannelId(chanId);
      positions.setPositions(positionsList);
      return positions;
    }
    // decide whether you want to return null, throw an exception or other outcome: depends on the constraints of your data
    return null;
  }

  private Position deserializePosition(List<?> props) {
    if (props != null && !props.isEmpty()) {
      final Position position = new Position();
      position.setSymbol((String) props.get(0));
      position.setStatus((String) props.get(1));
      position.setAmount((Double) props.get(2));
      position.setBasePrice((Double) props.get(3));
      position.setMarginFunding((Integer) props.get(4));
      position.setMarginFundingType((Double) props.get(5));
      position.setProfitLoss((Double) props.get(6));
      position.setProfitLossPercentage((Double) props.get(7));
      position.setLiquidationPrice((Double) props.get(8));
      position.setLeverage((Double) props.get(9));
      return position;
    }
    // decide whether you want to return null, throw an exception or other outcome: depends on the constraints of your data
    return null;
  }

}
```

To use this deserializer, it should be registered within the `ObjectMapper`:

```
private ObjectMapper initObjectMapper() {
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
  module.addDeserializer(Positions.class, new PositionsDeserializer());
  objectMapper.registerModule(module);
  return objectMapper;
}

@Test
public void deserializePositions() throws IOException {
  String json = "[ \"ps\", [ [ \"aa\", \"bb\", 123.45, 123.45, 567, 123.45, 123.45, 123.45, 123.45, 123.45 ] ] ]";

  Positions positions = initObjectMapper().readValue(json, Positions.class);

  System.out.println(positions);
}
```

*Suggestions*

If you have a possibility to choose/change the structure of the input JSON, I would recommend to reduce nesting and introduce more conventional KV mapping. For example, to represent `Positions`:

```
{
  "CHAN_ID": "string",
  "positions": [
    // Use the arrays here: [ "aa", "bb", 123.45, 123.45, 567, 123.45, 123.45, 123.45, 123.45, 123.45 ], 
    // OR transform the array into KV mapping: { "SYMBOL": "string", ... }, ...
  ]
}
```

This approach will allow to:

- reduce the risk of bugs, caused by magic numbers related with array indices for values;
- simplify the deserialization: read `Positions` automatically and have a custom deserializer for `Position` only, if the array structure is kept.

Also, I don't know what `Decimal` type means in the original code, so I replaced it with `Double`.

Comment: Tnx this is exactly what I was looking for :)